# Format JSON to form Grouped Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have data that needs to be formatted and summed up to be grouped.

```
sourceData ==>

var obj = 
  [
    {
    "level1": "A1",
    "level2":"B1",
    "level3":"C1",
    "amount":165
  },
          {
    "level1": "A1",
    "level2":"B1",
    "level3":"D1",
    "amount":156
  },

      {
    "level1": "A1",
    "level2":"B2",
    "level3":"C2",
    "amount":145
  },

    {
    "level1": "A1",
    "level2":"B2",
    "level3":"D2",
    "amount":110
  }]
```

Now I want data to be grouped so that total amount could be calculated on every level and it should appear like this:

```
  var Obj = [
      {
    "level1": "A1",
    "amount":576,
    "child":[{
      "level2":"B1",
      "amount":231,
      "child":[{
         "level3":"C1", "amount":165},
         {"level3":"D1", "amount":156}
        ]
    },{
       "level2":"B2",
       "amount":255,
      "child":[
        {"level3":"C2", "amount":145},
         {"level3":"D2", "amount":110}
        ]


    }]
  }
  ]
```

Although I have created the code that is working efficiently as a loop but I am unable to add amount and sum up into it.

```
 keys = ['level1', 'level2', 'level3'],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => (
        keys.reduce((level, k) => {
            var temp = (level.child = level.child || []).find(p => o[k] === p[k]);
            if (!temp) {
                level.child.push(temp = { [k]: o[k] });
            }
            return temp;
        }, r),
        r
    ), { child: [] }).child;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it looks like [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51784956/1447675). and this question has the same format. btw, please use only one account and ask additional information at the original question.

Comment: I got it from one of my friend, it might be your code, because he got this answer from Stackoverflow only....Can you help in it

Comment: so just copying is not really an attempt. please add this part as well.

Comment: Okay, i didnt checked this... This is YOUR CODE @NinaScholz

Comment: @NinaScholz can you please help in this

Answer (score 0):

You could take a helper array for the outer keys, to iterate them in the right order and reduce the array by taking a nested approach for an arbitrary nested data structure with a look up for each level of the result array.

If the key is not found in the actual level, generate a new object and return the child array for the next level search.

For pushing an object with the wanted keys to the most inner child, you could create a new object by omitting the used keys and take only the leftover keys and values.

Proceed until all object of the data array are iterated.

The result is a nested structure without `child` arrays in the leave objects.

Leter you could calculate the amount for every object by iterating the array and their children.

```js
function calculateAmount(array) {
    return array.reduce((s, o) => {
        if (!('amount' in o)) {
            o.amount = calculateAmount(o.child);
        }
        return s + o.amount;
     }, 0);
}

var data = [{ level1: "A1", level2: "B1", level3: "C1", amount: 165 }, { level1: "A1", level2: "B1", level3: "D1", amount: 156 }, { level1: "A1", level2: "B2", level3: "C2", amount: 145 }, { level1: "A1", level2: "B2", level3: "D2", amount: 110 }],
    keys = ['level1', 'level2'],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => (
        keys
            .reduce((level, k) => {
                var temp = level.find(p => o[k] === p[k]);
                if (!temp) {
                    level.push(temp = { [k]: o[k], child: [] });
                }
                return temp.child;
            }, r)
            .push(Object.assign(
                ...Object.keys(o).map(k => keys.includes(k) || { [k]: o[k] })
            )),
        r
    ), []);

calculateAmount(result);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: but the amount should be calculated and sum up on Level1 and level 2